# vPython does not import

Tags: python, ipython, vpython

I've installed vPython 7 on my Linux machine running Mint 18.2 64. Using the iPython environment and Python 2.7.12 I receive the following traceback when trying to import visual.

```
In [1]: from visual import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-96658a14bb68> in <module>()
----> 1 from visual import *

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/__init__.pyc in <module>()
    64                                frame, pyramid, ellipsoid, curve, faces, convex, helix,
    65                                points, distant_light, local_light)
---> 66 from visual.ui import display
     67 import materials
     68 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/ui.py in <module>()
      1 import cvisual
      2 from primitives import distant_light, local_light
----> 3 import materials
      4 
      5 # Code to provide special initialization for a display object, and overloaded

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/materials.py in <module>()
    150 texturePath = os.path.split( __file__ )[0] + "/"
    151 data = loadTGA(texturePath+"turbulence3") # the targa file is 512*512*3
--> 152 tx_turb3 = raw_texture( data=reshape(data,(64,64,64,3)), interpolate=True, mipmap=False )
    153 tx_wood = raw_texture( data=loadTGA(texturePath+"wood"), interpolate=True)
    154 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/materials.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     68         cvisual.texture.__init__(self)
     69         for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
---> 70             self.__setattr__(key, value)
     71 
     72 class shader_material(cvisual.material):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I am not sure why the package refuses to import properly. Anyone seen this error before and know the cause?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

VPython looks *really* out of date.  The [repository](https://github.com/vpython/visual) was last active in 2012, and has a link to [another repository](https://github.com/BruceSherwood/vpython-wx) which is also deprecated:

> This incarnation of VPython will not be developed further; see this announcement for an explanation and this history of the development of VPython. Development efforts are now focused on a Jupyter notebook-based version vpython-jupyter and an in-browser version that requires no local installation at all and runs on mobile devices, at glowscript.org.

I'd recommend trying again with the mentioned [`vpython-jupyter`](https://github.com/BruceSherwood/vpython-jupyter) to have the latest and greatest, and work from there.